# How to let developers with non-Admin access edit Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have setup an Azure function as an Admin and now I want to let my developers edit and test it, without sharing Admin access with them.

How do I add them to our profile and permission them with non-admin access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Role-Based Access Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-configure) (RBAC) to grant your developers access to the resource group that contains your Azure Function. Simply add them to the `Contributor` role for that resource group.